# Logical consistency-based I/O error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. My server got accidentally shutdown. After restarting it, I am not able to access my database. I am getting the following error for a few tables:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   checksum (expected: 0xd1723da7; actual: 0xab6a6efb). It occurred
>   during a read of page (1:69592) in database ID 16 at offset
>   0x00000021fb0000 in file 'H:\BACK UP\SQL17052014\databasse.mdf'.
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log
>   may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
>   Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
>   can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
>   Books Online.

I tried `DBCC CHECKDB`. It was giving error in one page. I tried to repair that page but not able to do so.

Can any one help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If indeed it is only one page that is affected, you should be able to perform a page level restore to get the database back. Full details are here:
http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/10/13/how-to-perform-a-page-level-restore-in-sql-server/

This does assume that you have a recent full backup of the database.

Comment: Worth noting that you can only do this ONLINE in Enterprise Edition.  Standard Edition this is an OFFLINE operation.

Answer (score 0):

If the faulty page exists in a (non-clustered) *index*, the simplest thing to do is drop and re-create the index.

If the page is in the *table* itself (ie, the clustered index or heap), then the standard answer is: **restore from your most recent backup**. Either the entire database, or restore a copy and just copy over that one table, or something like the page-level-restore that the other answer mentioned.